# Heat issue. Only heating with hot water running

Tags: plumbing, heating

Why would I only be getting heat when calling for hot water. When just calling for just heat I get nothing. Boiler wont fire. Run the hot water and boiler fires right up and radiators heat. This is a new problem.

Comment: What make and model is your boiler, and can you draw out a diagram of how its controls are wired?

Comment: Look around the boiler area for a switch typically labeled "winter/summer" and see if it's in the "summer" position.

Comment: Could be any number of things depending on the components in your system.  Pictures help.

Comment: Sounds like you have a hydronic heating system, which provides both hot water and facility heating.  And it sounds like there's a control issue of some kind - loose wire etc. Given the information you have provided, we have no chance of narrowing it down, other than what Ecnerwal said. If you can add more info, you can [edit] your question.